# Are there governor limits for number of lightning components per app?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, governorlimits, lightning-experience

I am getting a warning in console log as:

> WARNING: Suppressed Error: Error::Input too long. [1, 999991]::Error: Input too long. [1, 999991]

Is it due to some governor limitations on number of components rendered? I may be rendering around 1K components on scree

Comment: Is it showing any line no where you get this ?

Comment: no..but after that warning it is also giving me following error every time new dynamic component is created:

Error in the server action response:Received exception event from server

Comment: Also, I noticed that it is an intermittent issue.